# Jquery UI slider showing error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Hi people am having a problem in MVC3 where my jquery slider is showing the following error to where i require the slider:

```
[object Object]
```

The slider is not visable the jquery script i have added is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#slider-range-max").slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            value: 2,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#Score").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#Score").val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value"));
    });
    </script>
```

and its refering to this field in my view:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Score)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Score)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Score)
    </div>
```

I have added the following jquery scripts into my view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"</script>
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/modernizr-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

if you require addtional information please ask me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add the following jquery scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Second add this to your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: 10,
            value: 2,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#PutYourValueHere").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
$("#PutYourValueHere").val($("#slider-range-max").slider("value"));
    });
    </script>
```

Where it says PutYourValueHere shown above - that corresponds with the model.PutValueHere.

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PutYourValueHere)
```

Follow these steps should work.

Comment: I Have tried this and it worked fine thank you daza aza will mark up your answer as correct perfect answer

Comment: may I suggest adding the latest version of jquery, rather than 1.6.2?

Comment: It works fine so it is not point to add in the latest as it does the same job thanks